# Have to use `pyenv exec` every time with pyenv

Tags: python, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I worked with `pyenv` many times before and didn't have any troubles, but recently installed the new Ubuntu 20 and `pyenv` doesn't work as I expect anymore.

I create a virtual environment and activate it as usual:

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.10.1 test
pyenv activate test
```

It activates the test env showing `(test)` at the beginning of every row in the terminal. But when I try using python, it still addresses the system version. To actually use the virtual env I have to type `pyenv exec` every time:

```
(test)$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
(test)$ pyenv exec python --version
Python 3.10.1
```

I want to use my activated virtual env without `pyenv exec` like I did before. How can I do that?

I tried

```
pyenv local 3.10.1
pyenv local test
```

but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on `pyenv-windows`, and found that I needed to run `pyenv rehash` after doing any `pip install`. After that, new shims are generated for the packages.